# Как проверить значение из бд запрошенное в input?

Tags: php, html

как проверить значение из бд запрошенное в input?

```
$before=$_POST['before'];
$after=$_POST['after'];
if(!empty($before) && !empty($after)){
        $query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE mytabl SET source='$after' WHERE source=$before ");
        $result= mysql_query("SELECT source 
                                FROM mytabl 
                                WHERE source='$before'");
        ?>
        <pre>
        <?php echo $result;
        $r=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        print_r($r);
        ?>
```

выводит Resource id #5

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

// $database - дескриптор подключения к базе данных

$before = mysqli_real_escape_string($database, $_POST['before']);
$after = mysqli_real_escape_string($database, $_POST['after']);

if (!empty($before) && !empty($after)) {
    $query = 'UPDATE mytabl SET source = ' . $after . '
                WHERE source = ' . $before;
    mysqli_query($database, $query);

    $query = 'SELECT source
                FROM mytabl
                WHERE source = ' . $before;
    if ($result = mysqli_query($database, $query)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo $row['source'];
    }
}
```